# Get exception after applying Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Get the following exception after update Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 today. Now I can't connect to TFS.

*Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.EnumeratedSparseTreeNode`1> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.SparseTree`1.EnumParents(System.String, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.EnumParentsOptions)'.*

Tried to register *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll* to GAC from path '*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\lfiy4m2k.1dh*'. Still not work. (I checked that *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll* with telerik JustDecompile, and it already has the method EnumParents.)

Thank you for your help.

Update: 
Attach the image:
[image]

Update: 
In short, in the end I've restored the system to an old one. That one has Visual studio 2015 with Update 1 installed. I may not update Visual studio 2015 with Update 2 currently.

---

Things I've tried:

1. Register Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll(14.95.25118.0) to GAC. Not working. This used to save my life before.
   gacutil -u Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll first. 
   gacutil -i Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll later.
2. Run devenv /log. ActivityLog.xml shows nothing help. Just tells that TeamFoundation.vsix is duplicate with something other.

   One extension is from a path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\sgafzsci.zbq. 
   The other one is from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer.
3. Try devenv /resetuserdata.
4. Clear contents in folder Component Model Cache.
5. Repair Visual Studio 2015
6. Reinstall Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.

   *Tried 5 & 6 several times.
7. Uninstall VS 2015 from control panel -> Program Features.
8. Run vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force from the programdata/package/{guid}/

   Delete all data in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0,
   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0, 
   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp,
   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio ( all data in this folder except the 10.0),
   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation,
9. Install an Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 in offline mode. 
   Still not working at this time.
10. Uninstall the vs 2015 with update 2 with command line /uninstall /force

    This time, I can't uninstall the updates from Windows Update now.... I assume that the environment is totally messed up. To tell the truth, I didn't check the windows update before this step. I checked this time, cause when trying to install visual studio 2015 without updates in offline mode, it tells me that the update 2 is already installed in the computer.
11. restore the system to an old version.

    I've experienced another April fool's day.

    PS: I've to mention that I use ProcessExplorer and search Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll, vshub.exe and denenv.exe both are having the latest Common.dll loaded.  Also, after step 9, I search in C: driver list all the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll files. Only the one from TestAgent is the old version. All else are the latest.

    PS: 1. run tf get still gives me the same issue.

    2. Install VS 2015 TFS PowerTools and use get from that gives me the same issue.
    3. Try C# code by calling the function [Workspace.Get()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139264(v=vs.120).aspx) gives me the same issue. Reference to old version of TFS related dlls still gives me the same issue. I don't understand why and didn't look into it deep.

Updated:

Reinstall the OS at end. This time, I installed Visual Studio 2015 enterprise version with Update 2. It works good.

Comment: if you do not want to spend time and investigate the issue, one suggestion would be repair the installation.

Comment: Thanks. Already try to repair the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. Still not work. I assume that the Visual Studio keeps use the old Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll somewhere. But I don't know where it is. A global search in C driver shows all the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll with the same version: 14.95.25118.0. Now I don't know where to continue.

Comment: post a comment here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/31/vs2015-update-2-and-tfs-2015-update-have-shipped/ Microsoft monitors the comments for issues

Comment: @magicandre, Thank you for your direction.

Comment: Did you try to clean the cache folder: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT  Yes. Still got the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/31/vs2015-update-2-and-tfs-2015-update-have-shipped/#comment-167833

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you. I'm emailing the guy from MS. I'll update the status in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but I have the same issue only when using the [*Diff All Files VS 2015* plugin.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e6390f80-c953-4896-bd93-a7dfeba9887b)
Resetting its settings from tools/options solved it for me.

Comment: I've lost the environment since I've restore the system to VS 2015 with Update 1. You may contact the guy in MS. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/31/vs2015-update-2-and-tfs-2015-update-have-shipped/#comment-167833

Comment: There is another channel to look for help from MS. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/assistedsupportproducts

Answer (score 1):

I had VS 2015 and TFS Power Tools 2013

I uninstalled 2013 power tools and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade to VS 2015 update2 and connect to TFS 2015.2, no issue occurs. You need to re-install your VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar issue in VS2015 after installing "Shelveset Comparer" extension.
"[Clear MEF Component Cache](http://vsixgallery.com/extension/f5028141-9dd0-4ac4-ae6d-0481ae9a940d/)" extension solved my problem.
Just install this extension and Click "Clear MEF Component Cache.." button under Tools menu.